# How to return an array to its first value? Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, filter

I need your help. In my Angular application, I accept an array and try to filter it by a certain field. The point is that I have the normal filtering working, however, I need to return the array to the very first value: as if the page had just loaded. I tried to do this with the spread operator, but when I click on it, I have no element on the page. Please tell me how to implement this? Thank you very much

HTML

```
<div>
    <select
      formControlName="category"
      (change)="filterProductsCategorySelectOption()">
      <option [value]="firstDataValue">Reset</option>
      <option
        *ngFor="let category of allProductsCategories"
        [value]="category"
      > {{category}} </option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div *ngFor="let product of filteredProductList" class="different"></div>
```

TypeScript

```
public allProductsCategories: string[] = ["electronics", "jewelery", "men's clothing", "women's clothing"]
public allProductList: any;
public filteredProductList: any;
public firstDataValue: any;

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.form = new FormGroup({
     category: new FormControl(null),
   })

   this.productService.getAllProducts().subscribe(value => {
     this.allProductList = this.filteredProductList = value;
   })
   this.firstDataValue = [...filteredProductList];
}

public filterProductsCategorySelectOption(): void {
   const categoryOptionValue = this.form.controls['category'].value;
   this.filteredProductList = this.allProductList.filter(el => el.category === categoryOptionValue);
}
```

Comment: use setValue / patchValue on the form

Comment: can You make a stackblitx mock example? I think that You have to use ngOnChange  to see when the component change value

Answer (score 0):

I've filled out your example to create a working Stackblitz.

HTML:

```html
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <select formControlName="category">
    <option value="reset">Reset</option>
    <option *ngFor="let category of allProductsCategories" [value]="category">
      {{ category }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let product of filteredProductList" class="different">
  {{ product.name }}
</div>
```

TS:

```js
 public allProductsCategories: string[] = [
    'electronics',
    'jewelery',
    "men's clothing",
    "women's clothing",
  ];
  public allProductList: any;
  public filteredProductList: any;
  public form;

  constructor(private productService: ProductService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      category: new FormControl(null),
    });

    this.productService.getAllProducts().subscribe((value) => {
      this.allProductList = value;
      this.filteredProductList = [...this.allProductList];
    });

    this.form.controls['category'].valueChanges.subscribe((val) => {
      if (val === 'reset') {
        this.filteredProductList = [...this.allProductList];
        return;
      }
      this.filteredProductList = this.allProductList.filter(
        (el) => el.category === val
      );
    });
  }
```

You don't need `firstDataValue` because you've already cached all products in  `allProductList`. You do need to make a copy of the `allProductList` as `filteredProductList` or else you will be changing the value of both when you reassign `filteredProductList` to the filtered list of products.

Also, instead of binding to the native `change` event, it makes more sense to  subscribe to the value changes of your input since you're using Reactive Forms.

[StackBlitz Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rv3ymh?file=src/app/app.component.ts)